# Why the space of probability measures is a subset of the measure space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Consider $\mathcal M (X)$ the measure space of a metric, compact space $X$ allowed of the weak-* topology induced by the semi-norms $\mu \in \mathcal M (X)  \mapsto |\int_X f ~d\mu| \in \mathbb R \cup\{\infty\}, ~ \forall f \in \mathcal C(X)$.

Then consider $\mathcal P(X) $ the subset of all probability measures over $X$. More precisely the subset of all $\mu \in \mathcal M (X)$ such that $\int_X d\mu =1 $ and $\int_X \phi ~d\mu \geq 0, ~ \forall \phi \in \mathcal C(X), \phi \geq 0$.

Why is  $\mathcal P(X) \subset E$, where $E $ is the unit ball in $\mathcal M (X)$? In other words, how to show it ?

I thought it could be seen in terms of its dual space. Since $(\mathcal M (X) , w-*)\equiv (\mathcal C (X), \| \cdot \|_\infty)'$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your definition of positivity is wrong.

Comment: @mookid You'r right mookid I forgot $\phi \geq 0$ Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The norm on $\mathcal{M}(X)$ as a dual space of $\mathcal{C}(X)$ is
$$
\lVert \mu \rVert = \sup_{\lVert f \rVert_\infty \leq 1} \lvert \mu(f) \rvert = 
 \sup_{\lVert f \rVert_\infty \leq 1} \left\lvert \int f \, \mathrm d\mu \right\rvert.
$$
Now suppose $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(X)$. Observe that $g \geq f$ implies $\int g \, \mathrm d\mu \geq \int f\,\mathrm d\mu$ since $g-f \geq 0$ so that $\int (g-f)\,\mathrm d \mu \geq 0$.

For all $f$ with $\lVert f \rVert \leq 1$ we have $2 \geq 1 - f \geq 0$, so that by integrating over $\mu$ we see that
$$2 \geq \int (1-f)\,\mathrm d\mu \geq 0$$ and hence
$-1 \leq \int f\,\mathrm d\mu \leq 1$ which shows $\lVert \mu \rVert \leq 1$.